# ASP.NET mvc hiding webgrid columns

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My cshtml file receiving some bool values within a model (+data to build a webgrid). Depending on bool values some of webgrid columns must be shown and some hidden, for example i have:
`Name`, `Surname`, `Job` columns in webgrid, but i have `SurnameBool = 0` which means only `Name` and `Job` columns must be shown. I have tried to use code from other answers but unfortunately i am novice in JavaScript so please can you advice me how to add css `display : none` property to columns within a webgrid, basing on `@if(ColumnNameBool)` results.

```
WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(item2.ListOfWorkData, canSort: false, rowsPerPage: 15);

<div id="divWebGrid" class="row">
    @if (item2.ListOfWorkData.Any())
    {
        @grid.GetHtml(
                             tableStyle: "table",
                             headerStyle: "table_HeaderStyle",
                             footerStyle: "table_PagerStyle",
                             rowStyle: "table_RowStyle",
                             alternatingRowStyle: "table_AlternatingRowStyle",
                             selectedRowStyle: "table_SelectedRowStyle",
                             columns: grid.Columns(
                                 grid.Column("ProjectName", @Resources.Localization.project, format: @<text>
                                    @if (Model.ColumnsNeeded.ProjectNameBool)
                                    {
                                        <span class="display-mode"><label id="ProjectNameLabel">@item.ProjectName</label></span>
                                    }
                                </text>,style : "hidden-column"),
                                 grid.Column("Activity", @Resources.Localization.activity, format: @<text>
                                    @if (Model.ColumnsNeeded.ActivityBool)
                                    {
                                        <span class="display-mode"><label id="ActivityLabel">@item.Activity</label></span>
                                    }
                                </text>, style: "p60"),
                                 grid.Column("ProjectEndDate", @Resources.Localization.start_date, format: @<text>
                                    @if (Model.ColumnsNeeded.ProjectStartDateBool)
                                    {
                                        <span class="display-mode"><label id="ProjectStartDate">@item.ProjectStartDate</label></span>
                                    }
                                </text>, style: "p60"),
                                 grid.Column("ProjectEndDate", @Resources.Localization.end_date, format: @<text>
                                    @if (Model.ColumnsNeeded.ProjectEndDateBool)
                                    {
                                        <span class="display-mode"><label id="ProjectEndDate">@item.ProjectEndDate</label></span>
                                    }
                                </text>, style: "p60")
                             )
                     )
    }
```

Comment: can you try something like 
                  @if(ColumnNameBool){ render column }

Comment: please add code of your webgrid

Comment: I have never met such decision so far, can you write how should i point to column directly, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create grid with null source:

```
WebGrid grid = new WebGrid<Your item type>(null, canSort: false, rowsPerPage: 15);
```

Bind you grid with source:

```
grid.Bind(item2.ListOfWorkData, rowCount: <total row count>, autoSortAndPage: false);
```

Create your set of columns depending of ColumnNameBool value:

```
var gridColumns = new List<WebGridColumn>();
@if(ColumnNameBool)
{          
      gridColumns.Add(grid.Column("ProjectName", 
                       @Resources.Localization.project, format: @<text>
                                @if (Model.ColumnsNeeded.ProjectNameBool)
                                {
                                    <span class="display-mode">
                                    <label id="ProjectNameLabel">
                                    @item.ProjectName</label>
                                    </span>
                                }
                            </text>,style : "hidden-column"));
               )
             //... add other required columns here
}
else
{
      //create here another list of columns that required
      gridColumns.Add(...);   

}
```

Finally assign list of columns to grid:

```
@grid.GetHtml(<styles>, columns: gridColumns.ToArray());
```

Comment: Probably it wont work for me, i am going to have about 40+ columns in my table, it is just impossible to write all combinations of them, but thank you.